# Haskell get set thread name

Tags: haskell

When I print something in Java, I usually append the name of the thread to the print statement so I know what thread is running what print statement. How do I get and set the thread name in Haskell? If I can't set the thread name, how do I make a thread that has a given name?

Note: I usually give my threads descriptive names like "GUI_thread", "main_thread", "database_thread", etc

Comment: AFAIK you can just use the `Show` instance of `ThreadId` (get with [Control.Concurrent.myThreadId](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:myThreadId) or from `forkIO`) to print it - of course that will give you something like `ThreadId 42` - don't know if you can assign this a name - but should be possible to keep a associative map with the names yourself if you want to

Comment: wait ... Hayoo found something: [labelThread](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-Conc-Sync.html#v:labelThread) - should be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Carsten that's it. A string that makes the identification of threads easier. Write a 2-5 line example where you set the thread name and then print off the thread name and unless someone comes up with something better I will give it best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in a comment you can use [`labelThread`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-Conc-Sync.html#v:labelThread) to give the thread a label. Sadly I could not find a way to pull this label back out (all I found was this [invalid ticket](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-tickets/2014-November/018647.html) where someone wanted to do just this).

But as descriped in [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch15.html#sec_conc_eventlogging) you can get an event-log view on this:

(straight from there – I hope nobody minds):

```
main = do
  t <- myThreadId
  labelThread t "main"
  m <- newEmptyMVar
  t <- forkIO $ putMVar m 'a'
  labelThread t "a"
  t <- forkIO $ putMVar m 'b'
  labelThread t "b"
  traceEventIO "before takeMVar"
  takeMVar m
  takeMVar m
```

You then should compile it with the `threaded` and `eventlog` switches set:

```
ghc mvar4.hs -threaded -eventlog
```

and can call it with `+RTS` and `-l`:

```
./mvar4 +RTS -l
```

Finally you can look at the output with `ghc-evetns`:

```
ghc-events show mvar4.eventlog
```

---

### Naive self-implementation

That seems not to be exactly what you want, so here is a (very basic) example of how you could do it yourself (using just lists and an `MVar` to keep the association between the `ThreadId` and its name):

```
import Control.Concurrent

type Labels = MVar [(ThreadId, String)]

initLabels :: IO Labels
initLabels = newMVar []

labelThread :: Labels -> ThreadId -> String -> IO ()
labelThread labels threadId label =
  modifyMVar_ labels (\assocs -> return $ (threadId, label):assocs)

getLabel :: Labels -> ThreadId -> IO String
getLabel labels threadId = withMVar labels (\assocs ->
  case lookup threadId assocs of
    Just label -> return label
    Nothing    -> return $ show threadId)
```

and you can use it like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  ls <- initLabels
  myId <- myThreadId
  getLabel ls myId >>= print
  labelThread ls myId "my Thread"
  getLabel ls myId >>= print
```

which would get you:

```
λ> :main
"ThreadId 50"
"my Thread"
```

Obviously this might not be a good idea if you create lots of threads. At the very least you should add something to remove the label again at the end of your thread:

```
removeLabel :: Labels -> ThreadId -> IO ()
removeLabel labels threadId =
  modifyMVar_ labels (return . filter ((/= threadId) . fst))

forkLabeledIO :: Labels -> String -> IO () -> IO ThreadId
forkLabeledIO labels label computation = forkIO $ do
  myId <- myThreadId
  labelThread labels myId label
  computation
  removeLabel labels myId
```

... yeah I know: nasty – and of course a `Map` might be a better idea too – but I hope you get the basic idea

Comment: @dfeuer ... thanks (seems I need a spell-checker ... sorry for that)

Comment: "getLabel" and "labelThread" seem useful for printing thread names. I don't understand why it is obviously a bad idea to label lots of threads (unless there is labeling overhead) and I don't understand why it is necessary to remove the label. Having lots of threads with labels isn't really a problem because I only label long running threads like main, GUI, etc. I am trying to re-create a feature from Java that I used for poor man's multi-threaded debugging: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-cafe/5b_myuBoU8o

Comment: it can be a bad name because the way I demonstrated it will keep those names in the list - so if you have really lots the list gets longer which means more memory and - what is probably worse - `lookup` might take to long - to counter this you could use `Map` and the other problem is lessened if you "dispose" it at the end of the thread as I tried to show in `forkLabeledIO`

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing. You're adding the "(ThreadId, String)" tuples to the IO state monad and it gets bigger every time you call "labelThread". In practice I don't think that it's a problem because in Java I always named a thread once and only once - at its start of execution - and I only named the long running threads. Like I said, this is like my second or third day of learning Haskell, but I appreciate it.

Comment: yes exactly! - for learning and testing it is surely no problem - to be honest I am really surprised that you cannot get the in-build *label*  back out - maybe I am just to stupid to find it though - but I guess someone would have noticed by now

Comment: you're not stupid. One more thing. The way I normally do multi-threaded debugging... groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-cafe/5b_myuBoU8o  ... It's basically just giving each thread a name and make my print line statements provide a thread name and a one or two line stack trace (formatted like a Java exception so that the IDE jumps to the right file when you click on it). I'm kind of 22 years old and don't have that much experience in Industry. Is that a good way of doing multi-threaded debugging? Because in college it was like my go-to method.

Comment: to be honest I know no good way of debugging multi-threaded programs - it's always a mess - but yes it's fine - although you should not really run into the same problems you might know from Java ... have a look at the link to online book I provided - it provides a lot of information, best practices and tool recommendations

Comment: Oh wow, I ordered that book on Amazon yesterday. Anyway, the first thing I'm going to implement in Haskell is my Java style multi-threaded print debugger. Would you like a copy - it's very useful to use with EclipseFP.

Comment: sure just put it on github or something and post on reddit.com/r/haskell when you are done :D